# CSS "background-size: cover" not working on Android device

Tags: android, html, css, ionic4

I'm woking with an Ionic 4 Angular application and styling an `<ion-slide>` to display a background.

I'm using `background-size: cover;` in the CSS. Everything looks perfect in the browser and on an iOS device, but when running on an Android device, the background is not displaying correctly. I've attached some screenshots for reference below.

HTML:

```
<ion-slide class="step-two">
    <div class="slide-container">
      <h1>Find</h1>
      <p>Tap into stockists and discover where to buy your favourite beers.</p>
      <ion-img class="swipe-img" src="../../assets/imgs/swipe.svg"></ion-img>
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
```

CSS:

```
.step-two {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(121, 168, 226, .9), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)), url("../../assets/imgs/onboarding-bg2.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}
.slide-container {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Correct display on an iOS device:

[image: Correct background covering]

Incorrect display on an Android device:

[image: Undesired background covering]

I've tried to set a height on the slide like so:

```
.step-two {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(121, 168, 226, .9), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)), url("../../assets/imgs/onboarding-bg2.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
    height: 100%; // This didn't work. The height was less than the view height of the device (about 30% in fact). Also tried 100vh which filled the view height but didn't fix the cover issue.
}
```

In addition to the cover size not being correct, it seems the background image is also not centered on Android.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the good old `!important` on the background-size?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using background size as "Cover" try using "100% 100%". Which will set 100% width and 100% Height of the image according to the container. Like this:

`background-size:100% 100%;`

Example:

```
.step-two {
background: linear-gradient(rgba(121, 168, 226, .9), rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)), url("../../assets/imgs/onboarding-bg2.jpg") no-repeat center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
height: 100%;
```

}

Comment: Thanks! It's better but still not perfect. The height and width are correct (the image size is matching the view) and the image is centered but the image is now squashed in terms of it's width. The left and right edges are not being cropped. Any ideas?

Comment: Send me some screenshots!